# Change custom taxonomy archive permalink

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have created a custom post type named video and a custom taxonomy for video as video_category. I have created a page template with the name taxonomy-video_category.php. So that the categories of the videos can be viewed on the URL mysite.com/video_category/{category_name}.

I need to change this URL to mysite.com/videos/category/{category_name}. I tried the plugin Custom Permalinks. But it does not allow me to change this URL on edit of the taxonomy video_category.

I want to do this preferably without the use of plugins. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`rewrite` parameter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/) to customize the taxonomy permalinks.

Here's an example which links the taxonomy to the default `post` post type:

```php
register_taxonomy( 'video_category', 'post', [
    'public'   => true,
    'rewrite'  => [
        'slug' => 'videos/category',
    ],
    // ... your other parameters ..
] );
```

Don't forget to flush the rewrite rules — just visit the permalink settings admin page.

And if the taxonomy is being registered by a plugin and (just in case) it doesn't allow changing the rewrite *slug*, there's a filter hook you can use to change the slug programmatically: [`register_taxonomy_args`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/register_taxonomy_args/). Here's a simplified example:

```php
add_filter( 'register_taxonomy_args', 'my_register_taxonomy_args', 10, 2 );
function my_register_taxonomy_args( $args, $taxonomy ) {
    if ( 'video_category' === $taxonomy ) {
        $args['rewrite'] = (array) $args['rewrite'];
        $args['rewrite']['slug'] = 'videos/category';
    }

    return $args;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Will this change the slug overall like when using get_terms() or just in the URL?

Comment: It will change both, I mean when using `get_term_link()` and functions using it - that's how it works when the permalink structure is customized via that `rewrite` param. But you can try and see for yourself. :)